# Что значит ClassFanOutComplexityCheck

Tags: java

Не могу понять, что значит ошибка чекстайла?

```
"Class Fan-Out Complexity is 23 (max allowed is 22)."
```

И как ее исправить?

Answer (score 1):

> The number of other classes a given class relies on.

Количество других классов, которые используются в данном. (стандартные, String, ArrayList и т.д. не учитываются)

Подробное описание того, что и как считается см. тут - [ClassFanOutComplexity](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_metrics.html#ClassFanOutComplexity)

Comment: на что влияет количество классов, можно ли изменить предел?

Comment: @ks_on_v Влияет на сложность сопровождения этого класса в будущем. Как перенастроить - читайте в документации по ссылке